# Simulate PrintScreen key press

Tags: scripting, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool

I want to write a script that changes the window focus, and sends keyboard commands, such as print screen, and arrow keys, to the system. As in I need print screen to capture my desktop, not the script window.

I can do it manually, but it is tedious, as I have a lot of screenshots to take.

I see that I can use xdotool for this.
What is the key name for print-screen?
(I am away from my Linux terminal, and I can't use xev remotely)
alternatively, how can I figure out the names of keys, using something besides xev?

Comment: please state your question

Comment: Depends which OS you are on. `osascript` can do this easily although I'm not sure your OS has it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to "invoke" the <kbd>PrtSrn</kbd> button, if you install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) then you can do the following in your script:

```
import -window root output.png
```

If you want a particular window you can try to find its id first with `wmctrl` (the following captures the Firefox window displaying this post, the `grep`-ed string has to be unique.):

```
id=$(wmctrl -l | grep -F 'bash - simulate' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
import -window $id window.png
```

Alternatively, if you know the part of the screen you need is on a particular place, you can grab the whole screen and then use [`convert -chop`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop) to cut out what you need from the desktop image.

ImageMagick is normally installed using a package named `imagemagick`

Comment: is that python?

Comment: No that actually a command that is part of the ImageMagick suite.

Comment: Do you know how I might specify a particular area of the screen? I just started reading the man page

Comment: How do I get the window ID?

Comment: The window ID is not so easy to get you can use `wmctrl` to extract it based on the window title. If the window is positioned on the same spot every time, I would grab the screen and use [`convert -chop`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop) to select the part you need.

Comment: I may have to wait to work on this. Until I can get back to my terminal. I was just reading about xwininfo to try and get window ID's

Comment: @j0h Your question stated you wanted the desktop, so that is not what you want?

Comment: well, most of my desktop. I probably dont need the view of my panel icons etc

Comment: @j0h I added some more to the answer, hope that helps you solve the problem.

Comment: @j0h `xdotool` has ways to find a window (mainly the `search` command).